# Getting address of a new contract in truffle with javascript?

Tags: web3js, truffle

I am trying to use truffle-contract and web3 to create a new instance of a contract and then get the contract address of the contract that I just created.

I have tried the following code with a few similar variations but I get an error of the form "Cannot set property 'contractInstance' of undefined"

I understand it can take a few minutes to create the contract but how do I factor this into the code?

What is the recommended way to do this, or best practice?

```
  createNewContract(value) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const contract = require('@truffle/contract');
      const transferContract = contract(tokenAbi);
      transferContract.setProvider(that.web3);
      transferContract.new({from: account}).then(function(instance) {
        this.contractInstance = instance.address;
        return instance.address;
      }).then(function(status) {
        if (status) {
          return resolve({status: true});
        }
      }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
        return reject('new contract error');
      });
    });
  }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by reducing it to a simply async function

```
  async createNewContract() {
    const that = this;

    const contract = require('@truffle/contract');
    const transferContract = contract(tokenAbi);
    transferContract.setProvider(that.web3);
    let newContract = await transferContract.new({from: that.account});
    this.contractInstance = newContract.address;
    console.log('the new contract created has an address of'+this.contractInstance);
    return this.contractInstance;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution could be:

```
// setting up web3 provider
const Web3 = require('web3')
const web3 = new Web3('ws://localhost:8545')
// import contract artifacts from build folder generated
// as a result of truffle migrate command
const sampleContractArtifact = require('./build/SampleContract')

const ContractInstance = async () => {
  //This method find the network id to retrieve the configuration from truffle-config.js file
  const networkId = await web3.eth.net.getId();
  // Retrieve the Network configuration from truffle-config.js file
  const deployedNetwork = sampleContractArtifact.networks[networkId];
  // Initializing the contract
  const SampleContract = new web3.eth.Contract(
    sampleContractArtifact.abi,
    deployedNetwork.address
  );

  return SampleContract;
};

export default ContractInstance;
```

The above block of code assumes you are using `ganache` configured to run at port `8545` in `truffle.config.js`. However, it will work with any network, you need to update your `web3` provider accordingly.

Hope it will help.

Comment: Thanks, the async property really helped. I got things working inspired by your answer